# Will installing Java 8 on OS X affect Xamarin which, requires Java 7?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin on OS X to create Android apps.

I'm getting prompted to upgrade my java from 7.x to 8.x.  I know that in .NET upgrading from 3.5 to 4.0 mostly just adds features to the CLR.

I also know that .NET 1.0, and .NET 3.0 use different CLRs

Does an upgrade of Java from version 7.x to 8.x act like a parallel install of .NET (not affecting the other, both runtimes are available), or does it upgrade everything, possibly causing compatibility errors?

Answer (score 1):

From the Xamarin developer site:

Android also requires that a 32-bit Java JDK 6 (1.6) be installed. Later versions of the JDK can also be installed alongside JDK 6, if required by your machine.

So, I believe it would be ok to download Java 8